# Conditional Fields module not working when OR operator is used

Tags: 7

Using conditional_fields 7.x-3.x module
having two fields "category"(list containing a,b,c,d) and field "total rooms".

I have placed a dependency to show the total rums when category is "a" (OR) category is "c".

```
                      field_category       field_total_rooms is visible when field_category has value "a".
field_total_rooms                     OR
                      field_category       field_total_rooms is visible when field_category has value "c"
```

total rooms is being displayed when  category is "a" but 
total rooms is not getting displayed when category is selected as "c".
Any suggestion

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/105564/multiple-condition-in-conditional-field-doesnt-work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dependency should be like below:

```
 field_total_rooms  field_category     field_total_rooms  is visible when field_category has at least one of the values: a, c.
```