# Multiple condition in Conditional Field doesn't work

Tags: 7, entities

I am using [Conditional Fields Module](https://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) to show and hide fields according to the condition selected.

At first, I have a **Select List** with **3** Values (***Mind, Body, Soul***)

When I select ***Body*** the two fields (*Body, What are your diet Plans?*) shows up, like in Picture:
[image]

When I select Soul another Two fields Show up:
[image]

But When I select Mind, I get only one field, even though I have configured it to show two fields.
[image]

My Conditional Field Configuration is:
[image]

The issue here is, ***What are your prayers?*** field is configured to show when either ***Mind*** or ***Soul*** is selected from that Select List

I have configured it correctly using **OR** in the field condition but it(what are your prayers?) only shows while selecting *Soul* from the select list.

Any ideas what is wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was in the same trouble.

I just found that you can use one condition and use "Values input mode" to  Only one of these values (XOR) and Set of Values to the ID or Text of the value of the field you want.

Check that : http://www.interworks.com/blogs/gbivens/2010/06/04/tricking-drupal-webforms-allowing-multiple-options-same-key-value

EDIT : Here a picture  [image: Here a picture]

Comment: awesome, thank you very much... the link you posted was very good read.